# Powershell: Comparing Array (-notcontains) will not work

Tags: powershell

I want to compare two Lists of Arrays and to display the Delta in a third array:

```
$ListOfVMs
$ListOfRunningVMs

$StoppedVMs = $ListOfVMs | { Where-Object $_.Name -notcontains $ListOfVMs.Name }
```

This Filter delivers still the complete Content of `$ListOfVMs` and not only the Delta. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
$StoppedVMs = $ListOfVMs | Where-Object Name -notin $ListOfRunningVMs.Name
```

You need to pipe to `Where-Object`. `Where-Object` is what contains the script block (if you need to use it). You are also not comparing both lists here as you only reference `$ListOfVMs`.

Since you are comparing a single item against a collection, you will want to use `-notin` if the single item is on the left-hand side (LHS). `-notcontains` would be used if the collection is on the LHS.

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough. I am  using the Pipe!